# Your android sdk is missing corrupted?

Tags: android-studio

I have install the android studio while clicking on create a new project it shows this upside message

Comment: Please edit your post to provide a [mcve]. We have absolutely no information about your system, your programming environment, etc. How did you set up Android Studio, for example. What are your SDK settings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the sdk? Alot of people get this issue due to not having it, let me know if this helps, thanks

To download

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools

How-to

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html